# need a one query which will fetch the users from territory with (Custom Field on User User_Type__C is ='manager'

Tags: apex, soql, territory-management, territory

Requirment :- I need to fetch the assigned user to the territory for any account.

I have one account with territory and in that territory assigned user count is 5 and there is one user with UserType='Manager'.

I need  a Single SOQL query which will fetch the user with UserType='Manager' from Territory

Comment: Could you post what you've tried? Is this being ran as SOQL query, formula field, etc?

Comment: <ID,userterritory> UserIdActive=new map<ID,userterritory>select ID,userid,territoryid from userterritory where territory='001A3993AA3 ' Here I am Getting UserIds.And then again i am Querying the User for User with UserType='Manager'                                                                                      [select id from user where id in:userID and user_type__C='Manager'

Comment: Instead of two queries i Need a one query to get user from territory with User_Type__C ='Manager'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I think using a nested sub-select in the WHERE clause will work for you. You may need to tweak, but I think this will get you close:

```
[SELECT Id 
 FROM User 
 WHERE Id IN 
     (SELECT UserId FROM UserTerritory WHERE Territory='001A3993AA3 ') 
     AND User_Type__c='Manager'
```

Comment: but I really need Map <TerritoryId ,UserId> from territory.How can i Modify the query to get the map Of Territory Id and userid

Comment: You can initialise a map with a list. However, the map will be of type <Id,UserTerritory>. Within the map, you will be able to access the UserId from the `UserTerritory` object. The syntax is: Map<Id,UserTerritory> myMap = new Map<Id,UserTerritory>([soql query here]);